# Bind scroll event for a specific page in common javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to bind a scroll event for a specific html page but I don't want to put JS/jquery code inside that html file. I want to put code for this event in a common JS file, but I am not getting idea how to bind it.

Currently I have this scroll event code written inside same html file like this

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
     //Code for scroll event
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well straightforward answer to your question will be as follows

```
if (window.location.href == "some full url")
    $(window).scroll(function(){
       // your stuff 
    });
```

actually you have many properties in `location` object like `pathname` that can be useful.

However from the perspective of accuracy, you are somehow limiting yourself. Depending on technology (actually all of them support this) you can use bundles that allow you to have many js files in development time and only one in production. I'd suggest to use one of them.

**EDIT**

Your limitations are as follows

- Once you have hardcoded your url in the script it is tightly coupled to that url and if it changes (url rewrite or folder change) you'll have an error
- When you decide add the same functionality to another page, you have to modify your script
- If the project is transferred to another developer, he will have a hard time figuring out how the stuff works

**EDIT**

The following are some bizarre solutions, but in some circumstances, they might be acceptable.

1) You can bind to a variable on the page.

Having, for example, the following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var EnableScroll = true;
//]]>
</script>
```

In script file you can use

```
if (window.EnableScroll)
    $(window).scroll(function() { /* Stuff */ });
```

2) You can base on a specific html

```
<body data-enable-scroll="true">
<!-- stuff -->
</body>
```

and in script file

```
if ($("body").data("enable-scroll"))
    $(window).scroll(function() { /* Stuff */ });
```

Comment: Yes exactly keeping these limitations in mind, I asked this question. Because I am not trying to tightly couple this code. So, isn't there any little more generic way to achieve this.

Comment: Ya, these 2 solutions seems convincing, at least for few scenarios that I have at present. Thanks!! But is this the way everyone does it? Or including it in html itself is better?

Comment: @Abhi I'd suggest you to use `enable-scroll` at minimum. Maximum would be setup bundling and minification that would compress and join all your javascripts in one bundle and include different bundles to different pages. And don't use bizarre method 1 =)

Comment: But in that case you have to make 1 more request for fetching that bundle. So, you are suggesting to use method 2, is it?

Comment: Bundle means sole script for the whole page. Bundle is one JavaScript file that includes all js files (jQuery, bundles and `$(document).ready()` initializations).

Comment: I think this is good to have this way, but what about browser caching? User has to download different js file for different pages? Isn't this raises performance issues?

Comment: @Abhi These are two sides of the same coin. On one hand, having multiple js files raises an issue, because each file except the actual download time has "warmup" and "closing" time. With bundles you get rid of these and substantially reduce the download time. More about this you can read [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification)

Comment: @Abhi On the other hand, you have an issue you have just mentioned, if the bundle is different, even in one place, browser has to download the entire bundle. But in my opinion, this is not a big drawback of bundling and minification.

Comment: Thanks for these insights, for time being I guess I am good with these workaround approaches you suggested as my requirement is small as of now, later can think of bundling. :)

Comment: This answer is too old but working. Upvote from my side Thanks @Oybek . Is it possible instated of URL we can use class or id?